# Issue with ConnectAPI.NamedCredential Class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to utilize the NamedCredential Class. The getNamedCredential method works but the getExternalCredential method does not. I am able to see the external data from the named credential call but some of the data is coming back as blank. I need to pull back the custom header from the external named credential. This stores an API key I need to access to use in a JavaScript call-out.

I am a system admin and have the setup and config permission.

Any ideas why this does not work or any other way I can get this data?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.